# Efficient Code Refactoring

Tags: c#, optimization, montecarlo

Not being an experienced programmer, I was wondering if you could help me to find the most efficient way to refactor a part of source code.

Indeed, I have taken over a project where in one class I have one (public) static method which is around 3000 lines long. 
I would like to refactor it especially with regards to the fact that I will incorporate some multithreading in it.
Basically the code is a s follows:

```
> - Different kinds of parameter Initialisatoins need for the method
> - Monte-Carlo routine with random numbers generations and business logic
> - outut of results.
```

In my opinion the best way is to remove the staticity of the method and to build a "plain " class with a constructor and divide the Monte-Carlo routine in smaller functions.
However, I will have around 50 class memebers which  seems not too appropriate.

However, that is the only "not to disgusting" implementation that I came with.

What would be your advice.

Many Thanks,

Comment: You may have better luck getting answers if you post this on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of [creating new class from the function](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-method-with-method-object) is probably best one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the extract method feature to brake the function down into the 3 parts you just described. Then take each part and break it down even more by finding the logical independent parts of the code. But you can do more, define a monte carlo class that holds the independent monte carlo logic.